# Subset based on a list in nested dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm looking to subset a dataframe by evaluating if one of the elements in a column consisting of lists is part of the variable of another dataframe.

Specifically, I have a dataset of about 200,000 tweets (acquired via `rtweet`) that I'm looking to subset to contain only the tweets that include one (or more) of 10 hashtags in the sample. These 10 hashtags are the most frequently concurring ones in the sample, stored in hashtags_top.

The usual methods for subsetting don't work (that is, they give nonsensical results). I've tried utilizing `%in%` in several subsetting-techniques:

```
tweets_tops <- subset(tweets, hashtags %in% hashtags_top$Var1)
tweets_tops <- tweets[tweets$hashtags %in% hashtags_top$Var1,]
tweets_tops <- filter(tweets, hashtags %in% hashtags_top$Var1)
```

They all gave the same subset of 112 tweets, which is most definetly not correct, considering the top hashtag alone clocks in at over 11.000 tweets. I've also tried unlisting the tweets$hashtags column via

```
   vapply(tweets$hashtags, paste, collapse = ", ", character(1L))
```

with the same result.

The structure of the data is as following [since only the "hashtag" column is of concern here, I'll only include this one].

```
str(tweets$hashtags)
List of 196987
 $ : chr [1:4] "Professional" "dynamic" "website" "development"
 $ : chr NA
 $ : chr [1:4] "Professional" "dynamic" "website" "development"
 $ : chr "MeTwo"
....
```

The structure of the hashtags_top dataframe which is used to subset is that of a simple two column dataframe where Var1 contains the hashtags and Freq contains their frequency:

```
str(hashtags_top)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: chr  "deutschland" "nsu" "mequeer" "kochallenge" ...
 $ Freq: int  1691 1862 2359 2372 2756 2853 3773 3900 8292 11745
```

I've come to believe that the evaluation via `%in%` does not work due to the fact that there are multiple elements in the dataframe to be evaluated. That is, it only works if there is exactly one hashtag (and that one is part of the desired subset). So I'm looking for a solution that allows to check if any of the hashtags in a row is part of the top_hashtags, and if so, include it in a subset.

I guess one solution would be flattening the dataframe, subset, and delete duplicates - but I'd like to avoid that. Probably there is an easier solution to this particular problem, but even after looking around for quite a while I can't seem to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code to acquire these tweets using `rtweet`, or at least some sample data?

Comment: It appears your data frame column is actually a list of 196,987 elements not an atomic vector.

Comment: Bob gives a good example as to how the data is acquired below. Since it's been resolved, I won't give sample data now. rtweet is great for mining tweets though. Also, @Parfait, the column being the list didn't seem to be the problem, since unlisting it did nothing to resolve the issue. The trouble is with multiple elements in the original dataframe's rows that each need to be evaluated. That's why pmap() was necessary (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
rt <- search_tweets("#rstats", n = 180, include_rts = FALSE)
rt %>% 
    select(hashtags)  %>%
    pmap(~any(c('DataScience','PowerBI') %in% .x)) %>% 
    flatten_lgl %>%  
    mutate(.data=rt, keep=.) %>%  
    filter(keep) %>%  
    select(-keep)
```

The workhorse is `pmap`, which lets you map a function over the selected hashtag column. If any of the tags we want (in your case `hashtags_top$Var1`) are in the hashtags column, we get a true value. We bind that result to the tbl using `mutate`, `filter` the rows which have a `TRUE` result, and then remove the temporary `keep` column.

Comment: Awesome, that works great! Thank you! I think I'll have to look more into these map functions, they seem to come in handy from time to time.

I've noticed you need to be aware that %in% is case-sensitive. That is, for hashtags it makes sense to convert them all to lower (or upper) case to account for irregularities. Make sure to use sapply() for correct results (if anyone hast the same problem):
     sapply(tweets$hashtags, tolower)